# SSIS Using column name in Excel to do a Lookup

Tags: ssis, lookup

I have an Excel sheet that has data with column headers (names).  These column names that are in Excel exist as rows in one of my tables in the DB.  What I need to do is to do a lookup on these Excel column names against the table in my DB to retrieve the id value.  How do I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered using a script task to pull out the header names from the xls sheet? You can use OLEDB in a script task to read an excel sheet programatically into a datatable. This may be of interest - http://vb.net-informations.com/excel-2007/vb.net_excel_oledb.htm

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jay.  I was hoping there was an easier way to do that.  Anyways, what I did was to use Derived Column component and have those column headers (names) hard coded.  That does the job but obviously I am hard coding it which works for me for now.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could pull out columns in Excel to variables in SSIS. Then you could use the values in variables to get data from DB.  Also, by using for-each loop, you could set fixed number of columns each time if you have too many column names.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old question and I just stumbled on this. We faced a similar situation and we used a cache transformation to get around. You can dump the excel data to a cache (using a cache transformation) and then on the Lookup, you can lookup on this cache rather than an OLEDB table. We have done this multiple times with no problems.